# What are some good books about social consensus theory?

Tags: reference-request, social-contract

I am interested in reading more about the social consensus theory. I looked up online, but found nothing more than the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theory).

Is there a book, or any kind of reference for this topic?

Comment: You've tagged this as "social contract". Was that merely because it seemed convenient or do you view social consensus theory as integrally linked to social contract theory?

Comment: because of the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good start would be Habermas' Theory of Communicative Action. It is very complex and hard to get into for a beginner and even advanced students without guidance, though. But I think every contempory theory regarding social concensus has to deal with the theoretical framework established and defended by Habermas.

For an introduction, see [this Wikipedia entry](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicative_action)

Answer (score 2):

Nicholas Rescher (1993), *Pluralism, against the demand for consensus*.

is really non-trivial and, imho, worth reading.